# No item is added to the List (from the user class) from webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

No item is added to the List (from the user class) from webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad

Green works, red - no

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zpzg.png)

```
Private Sub Captcha_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    webcontrol = New WebControl
    webcontrol.WebView = New WebView
    webcontrol.WebView.Engine = engine
    webcontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Panel1.Controls.Add(webcontrol)
    webcontrol.WebView.LoadHtml("http://google.com")
    Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList.Add(New CaptchaKey("Test1", 10))
    AddHandler webcontrol.WebView.BeforeRequestLoad, AddressOf BeforeRequestLoad
End Sub

Public Sub BeforeRequestLoad(sender As Object, e As BeforeRequestLoadEventArgs)
            Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList.Add(New CaptchaKey("Test", 10))
End Sub

Public Class CaptchaKey
Public Key As String
Public Time As Integer
Sub New(Key As String, Time As Integer)
    Me.Key = Key
    Me.Time = Time
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please enter your code as text formatted as code not an image. Remember, we may want to copy it to test your code.

Comment: i added code check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Invoke(Sub()
                           Form1.UC_tasks1.CaptchaKeysList.Add(New CaptchaKey(CaptchaKey, 10))
                       End Sub)
```

It is working, guys